# Why does this goroutine block?

Tags: go, goroutine

This goroutine blocks...

```
go log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
log.Print("This doesn't print")
```

This goroutine doesn't block...

```
go func() {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}()
log.Print("This prints")
```

This goroutine also doesn't block...

```
go http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
log.Print("This prints")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is according to the spec:

> The function value and parameters are evaluated as usual in the calling goroutine

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements

In

```
go log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
```

The first parameter is

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
```

which will be evaluated before executing the function `log.Fatal` as a goroutine, thus blocking.

Answer (score 2):

`go log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))` is equivalent to

```
e := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
go log.Fatal(e)
```

of course it blocks. As to
`go func() {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}()`

it starts the execution of function as an independent goroutine. Then you call `log.Print("This prints")`, as a logger can be used simultaneously from multiple goroutines, so it prints.

Answer (score -2):

Hmm,
I ran program:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    go log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
    log.Print("This doesn't print")
}
```

And it seems to work well:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8000 -v
* Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1:8000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Fri, 24 Feb 2017 08:22:19 GMT
< Content-Length: 19
< 
404 page not found
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

My go version:

```
go1.7.3 darwin/amd64
```

Please specify more information about your runtime, like go version, architecture etc.